# assign of a value var to another var

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to give the value of a var to another here's what I tried :

```sh
for (( k=j + 1; k < $# + 1; k++ )); do
     eval $TABLE_CONT="'${!k}'" # i tried this
     printf -v $TABLE_CONT "%s" ${!k} # i tried this
     printf -v $TABLE_CONT ${!k} # i tried this
done
```

here's how i execute my program : `./bdsh --file file.json create table user this,that`

1. here's the output for the first attempt : `./bdsh: line 154: =this,that: command not found`
2. here's the output for the second attempt : `./bdsh: line 154: printf: '%s': not a valid identifier`
3. here's the output for the third attempt: `./bdsh: line 154: printf: 'this,that': not a valid identifier`

Comment: You never set your variable `TABLE_CONT`, as you can see clearly from your error message. In your first iteration, TABLE_CONT does not exist, and the _eval_ command is expanded to `eval =something`, where the _something_ depends on the value of the variable `j` and the way you invoke the program. This means that you are trying to execute the command `=something`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after some research i found that i could simply do that : `TABLE_CONT+=${!k}` and it works as i wanted